# Multiple onDismissed functions for one Dimissible widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was wondering if it is possible to have a `Dismissible` widget which does one thing if dragged for less than 25% of the screen and does something else if dragged more than 25% of the screen.

In the example below the first `onDismissed` function would trigger if the tile was dismissed in the red part and the other `onDismissed` function would trigger if it was dismissed in the grey part.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we don't have any widget like that you want.

You have to create what you want with `GestureDetector()`